# How to access the host filesystem from Java Card API

Tags: java, javacard

I want to access the host filesystem from my Java Card, I have been through the `java.io` and `javacardx.external` package definitions however it has been of little help. My goal is to check whether a certain path on the host device (Android Phone) is a valid dir or not.

Comment: What's wrong with `new File(String path)`?

Comment: It is a bit difficult for me to debug, the filesystem in question here is not the card filesystem, but the host filesystem. I am unaware is any special permission is required. The documentation is very lax.

Comment: For Android, yes, there's file system permissions, but I'm not sure what documentation you're referring to

Comment: Here is the link to docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/index.html

Comment: @cricket_007 In Java Card, there is no such thing as `java.io.File`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in Java Card is run on the SIM, the SIM provides a (security) related service to the phone, not the other way around. There are no direct methods for reading data from the host filesystem to the SIM.

To get the file system information you would have to encode such a service in your host and use it to provide the data to the SIM card (which obviously must be programmed to request and / or receive the information).

There are ways of requesting information from the *handset profile*, but those do not extend to any possible host file systems. You can find the related constants in the [`MEProfile`](http://www.andresteder.com/static/api/simtoolkitapi/sim/toolkit/MEProfile.html) which is part of the on card SIM API. These pieces of information can be requested through the [`ProactiveHandler`](http://www.andresteder.com/static/api/simtoolkitapi/sim/toolkit/ProactiveHandler.html) interface.

The above also shows a way how to retrieve information from the host, by *reversing* the half-duplex APDU communication protocol, which only handles commands initiated by the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback

Comment: One question, How does the contact transfer happen - Phone contacts to SIM contacts. I presume it is again initiated by the host?

Comment: A smart card is usually not a free running processor, it only executes when there is an APDU command send to it. So yes, usually the host initiates the half duplex APDU communication. It is of course possible to reverse the communication (with a request in the response and the request-response in the next command send to the card). A SIM card may request information from the host that way, but I don't see any requests for file information in these requests.

Comment: Extended my answer for this.

Comment: Thanks Maarten, I have a companion application to this on the host. I work for a VoLTE service provider here and my use case was (As we manufacture SIM cards in house) to write an applet so that I can read the host filesystem and check if the companion Android application (For managing the user accounts - Real time self service ) is installed, and if not prompt the user to install one. But it seems I have to make use of the App to turn off some flags on my SIM applet.

Comment: The biggest hurdle here is that as per Android eco system security I cannot initiate communication from the app unless the user has run it at least once.  So even if the user has installed the app but has not run it once, I will still show the popup.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. But this may not be the way out. You could maybe use an other way of communication to the user/app, i.e. send a message. But that's a bit out of topic with regards to this question.